# Native crash: IntentService

Tags: android, crash, native

we have an app in beta testing. On one of the devices we received a crash in Play:

**Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so**

In the fault message below there are several important things to notice:

1. The problem component is **IntentService** (but android not ours, we don't have such class)
2. signal 6 (SIGABRT)
3. device is XIAOMI and it is rooted (very possible it is the root of this crash...)
4. OS version is 4.4

Here is the fault message:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/cancro/cancro:4.4.4/KTU84P/4.8.22:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 25073, tid: 25116, name: IntentService[C >>> org.final <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 0000621c r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 00000006 r5 00000000 r6 0000621c r7 0000010c
r8 77415b10 r9 770ffd2c sl 76e900a8 fp 77415b24
ip 719a3034 sp 77415850 lr 400da169 pc 400e910c cpsr 000f0010
d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 fe8000003f000001 d5 000122e800000000
d6 0000000000000000 d7 00000000000022ec
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 5472656c646e6148 d17 616a2e6461657268
d18 00310020002c0031 d19 0020002c00300032
d20 0020002c00300031 d21 0020002c00380034
d22 0020002c00310035 d23 0020002c00340035
d24 bf29e90ee4c465e7 d25 3fd0c84cbbcf4669
d26 3fd0c84cbbcf4669 d27 bf56a5b479c28218
d28 3febe5311169afed d29 bfdffffffd0c5e81
d30 3fb19a64f765cb80 d31 3ef99342e0ee5069
scr 60000012

backtrace:
#00 pc 0002210c /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00013165 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
#02 pc 00013379 /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 000120a3 /system/lib/libc.so
#04 pc 000219c0 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 00048b1f /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+78)
#06 pc 0004d487 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+146)
#07 pc 0005023f /system/lib/libdvm.so
#08 pc 0006a469 /system/lib/libdvm.so (Java_java_lang_Class_getDex(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*)+144)
#09 pc 0002034c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#10 pc 00050fcf /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#11 pc 000297e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#12 pc 00030c6c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#13 pc 0002e304 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#14 pc 00063431 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#15 pc 00063455 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#16 pc 00058133 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#17 pc 0000d248 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#18 pc 0000d3e0 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
400e90ec e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000
400e90fc ea006df3 e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000
400e910c e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000
400e911c ea006deb e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000
400e912c e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000
400e913c ea006de3 f200429a bf0080b9 f040f891
400e914c 4001e92d f2c02a04 2a1080a5 8093f2c0
400e915c f2c02a20 2a408088 ea4fdb7f f1bc1c92
400e916c dd6c0f0a 0600e92d 0f40f1bc f500dd4a
400e917c f5016e80 ebae7920 ea4f0e09 ea4f5e4e
400e918c f50e5e5e ebbc7e20 dd3b1f9e f04fbfc4
400e919c ebd9090a dd35199e 0a0eeb01 0a3ff02a
400e91ac 1c9eebac bfd245e1 0c09ebac f04f46e1
400e91bc f8910c00 f891f240 f921f280 f921028d
400e91cc f8da428d f1b93000 f9000901 f900028d
400e91dc f10a428d d1ee0a40 0f00f1bc f5bcd02b

code around lr:
400da148 447b4b13 42b3e010 6a1ed10e 44784811
400da158 ec7ef7fb ea0af00d 46224631 efccf00e
400da168 d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb
400da178 44782403 ec6cf7fb f001e002 6804fa23
400da188 fa20f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003b26a
400da198 0003b25e 0003b256 0003b232 bf7ef7ff
400da1a8 4a3e4b3d e92d447b b08b43f0 4606589c
400da1b8 6823460d 930946a1 fa04f001 8000f8d0
400da1c8 d0482d00 f0104628 280ff919 d8444604
400da1d8 ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e8d4f00d
400da1e8 d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debb0
400da1f8 e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478
400da208 4a2aec28 46332120 a801447a f990f013
400da218 a8012101 fcaef01a 46061c42 e011d104
400da228 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622
400da238 1c43e910 d11e4607 f9c4f001 29046801
```

I have searched through lots of posts. This problem appeared only once but it can appear... What is the cause to this? How to prevent it? Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: My advice is to not worry about this types of error. Most of the times it's caused by the OS

Comment: @Pedro I am thinking the same. But the users will be angry, right? They think it's an error in the app. Do I have a chance to tell them it's been their OS?

Comment: It this an isolated case or it keeps happening?

Comment: It was the 1st case but we haven't spread it among lots of people - 10 and the very 1st one had this problem. Ok, I will let it be and comeback if it's occuring more often. Thanks Pedro.

Comment: The problem is worse... We received the very same error, this time on a HTC device. Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so the problem is with Apk Protect and not with Retrofit.

Currently, the ApkProtect supports only versions 2.1-4.2.